# 100% height div that sits inside a fixed element?

Tags: css

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yvm17xq1/)

```
<header>
    <p>
        header stuff
    </p>
     <div id="dropdown">
         <p>
             a
         </p>
         <p>
             b
         </p>
         <p>
             c
         </p>
   </div>
</header>
```

I have a header that's fixed. Inside this I have a dropdown which i want to be 100% height of the page, yet setting height to 100% makes it 100% height of the parent element. Is there anyway to set it to be 100% of the page?

Comment: Please be more precise. Or even better provide sample image how it should look like.

Comment: How hard is 100% of the page to grasp - I've provided a jsfiddle.

Comment: you could set the height of the dropdown with `calc(100vh - 100px);` (the viewport height minus the header height). Anyway this is not equivalent to the page height

Comment: Or for `.dropdown` add `padding-top: 100px; height: 100vh;top: 0; z-index: -1`

Answer (score 0):

change .dropdown to:

```
#dropdown{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: tomato;
  top: 100px;
}
```

updated fidde [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yvm17xq1/1/)